# How to consolidate multiple string values into one result from query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have restaurants with multiple "Type" attributes. Even when I "SELECT DISTINCT" the code return 4 rows which is a little weird, but I want them all to be returned in the same row.

The code looks a little like this:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  Type
FROM 
  restaurant_table
```

My return now:

```
Name                 Type
Restaurant_1         Asian
Restaurant_1         Japanese
Restaurant_1         Sushi
Restaurant_1         Alcohol
```

What I would want it to look like:

```
Name                 Type
Restaurant_1         Asian, Japanese, Sushi, Alcohol
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  Name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Type)
FROM 
  restaurant_table
GROUP BY
  Name
```

Comment: Receiving "User-defined transform function group_concat must have an OVER clause" error

Comment: @Bbb No error in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcc307/1 . Post your complete query.